# Send and receive int C++

Tags: c++, sockets, int

How to send to server 4 bytes `int` and on server side conver this buffer to int.

**client side:**

```
void send_my_id()
{
 int my_id = 1233;
 char data_to_send[4];
 // how to convert my_id to data_send?
 send(sock, (const char*)data_to_send, 4, 0);
}
```

**server side:**

```
void receive_id()
{
 int client_id;
 char buffer[4];
 recv(client_sock, buffer, 4, 0);
 // how to conver buffer to client_id? it must be 1233;
}
```

Comment: How about atoi for the receive, and itoa for the send?

Comment: Yup - sending/receiving text will work, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may simply cast the address of your `int` to `char*` and pass it to `send`/`recv`. Note the use of `htonl` and `ntohl` to deal with endianness.

```
void send_my_id()
{
 int my_id = 1233;
 int my_net_id = htonl(my_id);
 send(sock, (const char*)&my_net_id, 4, 0);
}

void receive_id()
{
 int my_net_id;
 int client_id;
 recv(client_sock, &my_net_id, 4, 0);
 client_id = ntohl(my_net_id);
}
```

Note: I preserved the lack of result-checking. In reality, you'll need extra code to ensure that both send and recv transfer all of the required bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The usual convention since the beginning of the internet was to send binary integers in [Network Byte Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (read big-endian). You can use [`htonl(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) and friends to do that.

Answer (score 0):

On sending side:

```
int my_id = 1233;
char data_to_send[4];
memcpy(&data_to_send, &my_id, sizeof(my_id));
send(sock, (const char*)data_to_send, 4, 0);
```

On receiving side:

```
int client_id;
char buffer[4];
recv(client_sock, buffer, 4, 0);
memcpy(&my_id, &buffer, sizeof(my_id));
```

NB: size of `int` and endianness must be the same on both sides.

Comment: And if the "endianness" *isn't* the same, then you *need* ntohl() and friends.  The best policy is to simply use ntohl() whether you absolutely need it or not - it's just a good habit.  IMHO...

Comment: ...better it be more than a good habit. IMHO you won't survive long with the above code in the wild (pun intended).

Answer (score 0):

C++

```
int receive_int_from_socket(int socket_id){
    int network_value;
    int value;
    int bytes_received = recv(socket_id, &network_value, 4, 0);
    if(bytes_received > 0){
        cout << "num of bytes received: " << bytes_received << endl;
        cout << "integer form received: " << ntohl(network_value) << endl;
        return ntohl(network_value);
    }
    return -1;
}

int send_int_over_socket(int socket_id, int value){
    cout << "sent number:" << value << endl;
    int network_value = htonl(value);
    int bytes_sent = send(socket_id, (const char*)&network_value, 4, 0);
    cout << "sent " << bytes_sent << " bytes" << endl;
    return bytes_sent > 0 ? bytes_sent : -1;
}
```